# Do gfci's have to be on a 20 amp circuit, or can they be on a 15A?

Tags: electrical, gfci

Do GFCIs have to be on a 20 amp circuit? Also if you use the receptacle type GFCI, do you just need one in a circuit or do all receptacles have to be GFCI?

Answer (score 8):

The amp rating of the receptacle and circuit do not depend on whether the receptacle is a GFCI or not:

- If you have a 15 amp circuit, you must have 15 amp receptacles
- If you have a 20 amp circuit, you can either have 20 amp receptacles, or 15 amp receptacles if there is more than one (e.g. a duplex receptacle).

It's not unusual to have a 20 amp GFCI in a residential setting since kitchens are A) required to have GFCIs, and B) required to have 20 amp circuits. You don't generally see 20A receptacles elsewhere in a house since there are virtually no home appliances that require 20 amps @ 110V.

Comment: @TomRobinson: that's not correct, it is both permitted and reasonably common to have 15A outlets on a 20A circuit, as long as the wiring in the walls is appropriate for 20A (i.e. 12 ga). The breakers have only one job: to protect the wiring in the building. Not to protect any equipment (or people, for that matter).

Comment: I'm in Canada, and it is not allowed here. I will delete my comment.

Comment: @TomRobinson: That's interesting, this isn't a US-only site so I don't think you should've deleted it! Frankly the original poster didn't say where he was located so you may be right in this case.

Answer (score 6):

1) You can have a GFI receptacle on either a 15 or 20A circuit. Keep in mind, areas like kitchens, bathrooms, laundry, etc, typically require 20A circuits for receptacles. For areas like outside and garages 20A circuits are always a good idea.

2) Either. 
You can have a GFI receptacle and feed everything downstream of it off the LOAD terminals protecting them, or you can use only the LINE terminals and anything downstream is then not GFI protected.

Comment: Just to clarify, when using the LOAD terminals, it is only the downstream circuit that is protected. Anything upstream of the outlet is not protected.